# Delphi RTTI TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Create doesn't support the class that has overload virtual method

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, rtti

I found TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Create doesn't support the class that has overload virtual method.
For examples

```
type
  TLog = class
  public
    constructor Create();

    procedure SaveLog(str: string); overload; virtual;
    procedure SaveLog(str: string; Args: array of const); overload;  virtual;
  end;

constructor TLog.Create(str: string);
begin

end;

procedure TLog.SaveLog(str: string);
begin

end;

procedure TLog.SaveLog(str: string; Args: array of const);
begin

end;


procedure MyTest();
var
  ttt: TLog;
  vmi: TVirtualMethodInterceptor;

begin
  ttt:=TLog.Create();
  try
    vmi:=TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Create(ttt.ClassType);
    try
      //
    finally
      vmi.Free();
    end;
  finally
    ttt.Free();
  end;
end;
```

While executed TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Create(), it will raise exception "Insufficient RTTI available to support this operation".
Anybody could help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This  message is raised because some parameters of the methods of your class is not emitting RTTI information.  This is the case of this method

```
 procedure SaveLog(str: string; Args: array of const); overload;  virtual; //array of const - doesn't emit rtti info.
```

replace with this one

```
type
 TConst = array of TVarRec; //this type has rtti information 
 ...
 ...
 procedure SaveLog(str: string; Args: TConst); overload;  virtual;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer soon but I got another problem. Please see the [RTTI & Variant Open Array Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793949/rtti-variant-open-array-parameters).

Comment: TConst is not a variant open array parameter, it is a simple dynamic array (of TVarRec). So treat it as a dynarray and not as an open array parameter, and all is well.

Comment: I think the real problem is Delphi RTTI doesn't support method with open array parameter.

Comment: Is there RTTI support for open array parameters, but perhaps not for variant open array parameters?

Comment: I have tested both "array of Integer" and "array of const". I got the same exception. By the way, I found this issue while I implemented unit test codes with Delphi Mocks. So this issue is not only Delphi RTTI issue but also Delphi Mocks issue. If you created Mock object that had open array parameter method, you would get the same exception.